# How do I fix a blurry arrow in an alias icon?

Tags: finder, icon

I keep an alias on my desktop. It points to a Terminal shell script .command file. The alias arrow appears enlarged and fuzzy. It's pictured here next to a normal icon.

[image: Blurry Arrow Alias Icon]

How do I correct the look of the arrow in this icon?

I have tried restarting Finder (also my computer) and recreating the alias.

Comment: That is bizarre, have you tried deleting the .DS_store file in your desktop?

Comment: Strangely the problem has right now gone away, or I'd try testing that right now. The only thing that's changed since posting my question an hour ago is plugging/unplugging into an external monitor.

Comment: @user3052786 Thanks for suggestion. Problem returned today and I tested it. Unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I was able to solve this problem by going to "Show View Options" (Right Click on Desktop Space) and adjusting the icon size. You can set it back to the size you had it originally but somehow making an adjustment refreshes the screen and the arrows come back sharp and clear.

Before I discovered this I tried making icons different resolution sizes thinking the arrow was trying to "match" pixel resolution - but that apparently isn't the case. I would have used the "change icon file name" but somehow I wasn't able to get "system" approval even though I'm the admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I figured out that the arrow is ok if the icon is not set as a perfect square, otherwise the arrow tends to go blurry. But again - there is a problem with the icon when it's not a perfect square. But there is good news too, it can be fixed in quite a strange way - just move the alias to the trash and somehow the arrow becomes normal after a couple of hours or after restart. Don't know for sure, just keep in the trash for a while and it will fix this blurry problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it! Do the following:

1. Delete the original alias.
2. Find the original file.
3. Change the view options (at the Toolbar) of the files to "Show items as icons".
4. Make a new alias and move the alias to wherever you want it to be.
5. All done!